# Using Sleep() prevent me to writing to a file

Tags: c++, sleep

I have some code that writes the system time to a file:

```
std::ofstream file("time.txt");

    char *date;
    time_t timer;
    timer=time(NULL);
    date = asctime(localtime(&timer));

while ( true ) {
      std::cout << date << ", " << randomNumber  << std::endl;

      if (file.is_open())
      {
        file << date;
        file << ", ";
        file << randomNumber;
        file << "\n";
      }
}

file.close()
```

When I let my program run and stop it in-between (its an infinite while loop), I am able to get data written to my file.

However, if I merely change the code to add a Sleep() timer. No data is written to my file. But I do see an output on the screen. Is this expected behavior? How do I ensure that even if I end my program execution mid-way, values are written to the file?

```
    std::ofstream file("time.txt");

        char *date;
        time_t timer;
        timer=time(NULL);
        date = asctime(localtime(&timer));

    while ( true ) {

        **Sleep(100); // wait for 100 milli-seconds**
          std::cout << date << ", " << randomNumber  << std::endl;

          if (file.is_open())
          {
            file << date;
            file << ", ";
            file << randomNumber;
            file << "\n";
          }
    }

    file.close()
```

If I close my file right after the sleep timer, it writes the data out. But the main reason I'm adding the timer, is that I want to slow-down how often my file is being written to ...

Comment: Which `sleep` function do you think you are calling? The `sleep` function in POSIX C takes it's argument in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: also is asctime a callback or interrupt or something because otherwise the same date will always be written ?

Comment: Richard, I am on a Windows platform, so Sleep() takes in arguments in milli-seconds. I'm using Sleep() as upper-case : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx. It is seconds for Unix, I believe. Ben, the program outputs the data and time. The time constantly changes, as confirmed by my std::cout. All, I'm confused about is why it doesn't write to my file anymore ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the buffer so the contents are written to the file. Call `std::flush` or change `file << "\n";` to `file << std::endl;` to flush the stream. When you don't call `Sleep` in your program, the contents of the buffer are written as soon as the buffer becomes full, however, with `Sleep` the buffer doesn't become full right away because there is a delay, so you don't see the contents written to the file.

Comment: Wow, HOW did you know that ? Thanks a tonne! I'd be spending hours trying to figure that out if it wasn't for your reply ...

Comment: @c0d3rz: I've read quite a bit about iostreams. Here is a [nice article about the stream buffers](http://www.angelikalanger.com/IOStreams/Excerpt/excerpt.htm) if you want to get more indepth.